# How to render the initial value's display field for a remote combo box?

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I want to render a [ComboBox](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.form.ComboBox) that has an initial value. The ComboBox is backed by a [JsonStore](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.data.JsonStore) that loads data from some HTTP endpoint. I expect the display field to be displayed, but instead I see the value.

As a workaround, I can wait to set the initial value until the store is loaded. But that seems like a hacky workaround for such a simple use case.

Is there an easier way to render the initial display field for my ComboBox?

Here is an example. You can drop this code in any [ExtJS 3.4 Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1cpt&view/editor).

```js
var remoteStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos',
    autoLoad: true,
    fields: ['id', 'title']
});

var remoteCombo = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
    fieldLabel: 'Remote Store (busted)',
    triggerAction: 'all',
    mode: 'local',
    store: remoteStore,
    valueField: 'id',
    displayField: 'title',
    value: '2',
});

// Workaround: only set the value AFTER the store is loaded.
// remoteStore.on('load', () => remoteCombo.setValue('2'));

new Ext.FormPanel({
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    items: remoteCombo
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not to override the missing feature (Yes, looks like it is missing):

```
Ext.define('Override.form.ComboBox', {
    override : 'Ext.form.ComboBox',
    
    defaultValue: null,
    
    initComponent : function() {
        this.setDefaultValue();
        Ext.form.Checkbox.superclass.initComponent.call(this);
    },
    
    setDefaultValue: function() {
        if(this.defaultValue !== null) {
            if(this.getStore().lastOptions === null) {
                this.getStore().on('load', function(store) {
                    this.setValue(this.defaultValue);
                }, this, {single: true});
            } else {
                // How to avoid else here? :-/
                this.setValue(this.defaultValue);
            }
        }
    }
});

//-------------------------
var remoteStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos',
    autoLoad: true,
    fields: ['id', 'title']
});

var remoteCombo = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
    fieldLabel: 'Remote Store (busted)',
    triggerAction: 'all',
    mode: 'local',
    store: remoteStore,
    valueField: 'id',
    displayField: 'title',
    defaultValue: '2', // <-- New Property
});

// Workaround: only set the value AFTER the store is loaded.
// remoteStore.on('load', () => remoteCombo.setValue('2'));

new Ext.FormPanel({
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    items: remoteCombo
});
```

I have not used ExtJs v3.4 for about 10 years or more..

Comment: *I have not used ExtJs v3.4 for about 10 years or more..* -- Wish I could say the same!

Comment: Thanks, I like this idea. One question: do you see any reason I *need* the new `defaultValue` property? In my case, really it is the initial value that I am loading from some other endpoint, not a default value for the combo box. I was able to tweak your code to use the `value` instead of `defaultValue` and basically defer the setting of that `value` until the store is loaded. It seems to work fine. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Now that I say that, I'll have to check how we're actually setting the value. If we're calling `setValue` rather than passing the initial value as a config, then perhaps I can apply a similar override to `setValue` instead of `initComponent`.

Comment: Depends on your code. You can use standard value or new defaultValue prop. The main idea is to use override mechanism to add new feature to ALL comboboxes. Depend on your project defauleValue or value can be used.