# How to render the initial display value for a remote combo box inside an editor grid panel?

Tags: extjs, extjs3

NOTE: I recently posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68010709) which asks about a simple remote combo box. This question is similar but not duplicate, because it places that remote combo in a remote grid.

I am rendering an [EditorGridPanel](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel). One of the columns uses a [ComboBox](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.form.ComboBox) editor. The grid and the combo box load their respective data from separate HTTP endpoints. How can I force the combo column to render the display field on initial load?

I found a few workarounds, but it seems like there should be an easier way. My workarounds basically force these asynchronous loads to be synchronous: first load the combo store, then load the grid store. This gets complicated if, for example, I have multiple remote combos in a single grid. Is there no way to force the combo to re-render itself after the underlying data changes?

Here is an example. You can drop this code in any [ExtJS 3.4 Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1cpt&view/editor).

```js
// Create a remote store for the combo box.
var remoteStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos',
    autoLoad: true,
    fields: ['id', 'title']
});

// Create the combo box.
var remoteCombo = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
    fieldLabel: 'Remote Store (busted)',
    triggerAction: 'all',
    mode: 'local',
    store: remoteStore,
    valueField: 'id',
    displayField: 'title',
    lazyRender: true
});

// Create the column model for the grid.
var columnModel = new Ext.grid.ColumnModel(
    [{
        header: 'Column 1',
        dataIndex: 'column1',
        width: 220,
        editor: new Ext.form.TextField()
    }, {
        id: 'column2',
        header: 'Column 2',
        dataIndex: 'column2',
        width: 130,
        editor: remoteCombo,
        renderer: (value) => {
            var record = remoteCombo.findRecord(remoteCombo.valueField, value);
            return record ? record.get(remoteCombo.displayField) : 'Loading...';
        }
    }]
);

// Create a local grid store with some fake data.
var fakeData = [{
    column1: 'row 1',
    column2: 1
}, {
    column1: 'row 2',
    column2: '2'
}, {
    column1: 'row 3',
    column2: '3'
}];
var gridStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    autoDestroy: true,
    autoLoad: false,
    fields: ['column1', 'column2'],
    data: fakeData
});

// Workaround #1: load grid store AFTER all required combo stores are loaded.
// remoteStore.on('load', () => gridStore.loadData(fakeData));

// Workaround #2: force the column to re-render all records after the store is loaded.
// Kludgy and also marks the records as dirty.
// remoteStore.on('load', () => {
//     gridStore.each((record) => {
//         var originalValue = record.get('column2');
//         record.set('column2', undefined);
//         record.set('column2', originalValue);
//     });
// });

// Render the grid.
new Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel({
    store: gridStore,
    cm: columnModel,
    autoExpandColumn: 'column2',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    width: 600,
    height: 300,
    title: 'Grid with remote combo',
    frame: true,
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can avoid synchronous load of the stores. Just put single listener for remoteStore 'load' event in the grid 'render' event. Something like this:

```
// Create a remote store for the combo box.
var remoteStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos',
    autoLoad: true,
    fields: ['id', 'title']
});

// Create the combo box.
var remoteCombo = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
    fieldLabel: 'Remote Store (busted)',
    triggerAction: 'all',
    mode: 'local',
    store: remoteStore,
    valueField: 'id',
    displayField: 'title',
    lazyRender: true
});

// Create the column model for the grid.
var columnModel = new Ext.grid.ColumnModel(
    [{
        header: 'Column 1',
        dataIndex: 'column1',
        width: 220,
        editor: new Ext.form.TextField()
    }, {
        id: 'column2',
        header: 'Column 2',
        dataIndex: 'column2',
        width: 130,
        editor: remoteCombo,
        renderer: (value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store) => {
            var recordIndex = remoteCombo.getStore().findExact(remoteCombo.valueField, value);
            var record = remoteCombo.getStore().getAt(recordIndex);
            return record ? record.get(remoteCombo.displayField) : 'Loading...';
        }
    }]
);

// Create a local grid store with some fake data.
var fakeData = [{
    column1: 'row 1',
    column2: 1
}, {
    column1: 'row 2',
    column2: 2
}, {
    column1: 'row 3',
    column2: 3
}];
var gridStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    autoDestroy: true,
    autoLoad: false,
    fields: ['column1', 'column2'],
    data: fakeData
});

// Workaround #1: load grid store AFTER all required combo stores are loaded.
// remoteStore.on('load', () => gridStore.loadData(fakeData));

// Workaround #2: force the column to re-render all records after the store is loaded.
// Kludgy and also marks the records as dirty.
// remoteStore.on('load', () => {
//     gridStore.each((record) => {
//         var originalValue = record.get('column2');
//         record.set('column2', undefined);
//         record.set('column2', originalValue);
//     });
// });

// Render the grid.
new Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel({
    store: gridStore,
    cm: columnModel,
    autoExpandColumn: 'column2',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    width: 600,
    height: 300,
    title: 'Grid with remote combo',
    frame: true,
    listeners: {
        render: function (grid) {
            if (remoteStore.lastOptions === null) {
                remoteStore.on('load', function (store) {
                    grid.getView().refresh();
                }, this, {
                    single: true
                });
            }
        }
    }
});
```

P.S.
I have fixed the renderer.
P.P.S. be careful with string and integer values by findExact.. AFAIK it is type-sensitive method.

Comment: I didn't know about [`Ext.grid.GridView.refresh()`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.grid.GridView-method-refresh). I think I can work with that. Thanks.